# Model does not move with bones after auto weights are applied

Tags: rigging, bones

So I followed an animation rigging video on YouTube but how come my mesh doesn’t move with the bones? I’m in pose mode and nothing happens to the mesh but only the bones were moving... been stuck for this problem for days. Need serious help.

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: For reference: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org

Answer (score 0):

Bones don't know how to deform the mesh until you give them instructions on how to, basically. This is done by parenting the mesh object to the armature. Select the mesh object, then the rig, and use the hotkey `ctrl + P` to bring up the parenting types. You should choose "with automatic wieghts". By doing this, blender calculates distances from bones to vertices of the mesh, and pretty accurately decides which bones will move which parts of the mesh. Keep in mind, you may have to paint some wieghts manually if the mesh deforms in an undesired way.

Anyway, once you've parented the mesh to the armature, you can select the armature, go into pose mode, and move the bones, which should move character as well.

If you'd like to see another good video about all these things, give this a look: https://youtu.be/mhQY2_gVoVg